# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "62b17d1c042bb5983133a3d" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Hotel"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy realizando un proyecto de node y mongo, pero al querer capturar el ID del hotel para ver si existe en la base de datos, me muestra el error:

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "62b17d1c042bb5983133a3d" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Hotel"

Este es el codigo de mi modelo

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const hotelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    phone: String,
    image: String,
    timesRequest: Number,
    adminHotel: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Hotel', hotelSchema);
```

El codigo de mi controlador es el siguiente

```
const { validateData, alreadyHotel, checkUpdateAdmin } = require('../utils/validate');
const User = require('../models/user.model');
const Hotel = require('../models/hotel.model');

exports.updateHotel = async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const hotelId = req.params.id;
        const params = req.body;

        const hotelExist = await Hotel.findOne({ _id: hotelId});
        if (!hotelExist) return res.send({ message: 'Hotel not found' });

        let alreadyname = await alreadyHotel(params.name);
        if(alreadyname) return res.send({message: 'This hotel already exists'});

        const updateHotel = await Hotel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: hotelId}, params, {new: true});
        if(!updateHotel) return res.send({message: 'Hotel not updated'});
        return res.send({message: 'Update Hotel', updateHotel});
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send({ err, message: 'Error updating hotel' });
    }
}
```

Ya intente de todo pero no logro solucionar ese error

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Hay dos errores básicos en tu lógica:

1. La consulta que estás haciendo con Mongoose no hace el [Cast](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html) automático del valor para `_id`, porque tu `Schema` [no define dicho valor](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html#the-strictquery-option).
2. No necesitas consultar la base de datos antes de intentar guardar un registro.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución a ambos errores es muy sencilla y dependerá de lo que quieras hacer.

Para evitar el error de Cast, debes convertir el valor `hotelId` a un `ObjectId`. Para ello te puedes apoyar del método incluído en Mongoose: [`ObjectId()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids). Por ejemplo:

```js
const hotelId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
const hotelExist = await Hotel.findOne({ _id: hotelId});
//...
```

Ahora el valor de `hotelId` será de tipo `ObjectId` y no tendrás el error de Cast.

Para evitar la doble consulta a la Base de datos para saber si un documento existe o no, lo puedes hacer en una sola consulta usando el método [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html):

Por ejemplo:

```js
exports.updateHotel = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hotelId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    const params = req.body;
    const updatedHotel = await Hotel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: hotelId}, {$set: params}, {new: true});
    if(!updatedHotel) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: 'Document not found'
      });
    }
    return res.status(201).json({
      success: 'Document updated',
      updatedHotel
    });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Internal Server Error updating hotel'
    });
  }
}
```

Es bastante sencillo usar el método `findOneAndUpdate`. Si no se consigue coincidencia con el filtro de búsqueda el mismo devuelve `null`, de lo contrario realizará la operación de actualización, y como estamos usando la opción `new: true` se devolverá el documento actualizado.

Por otro lado, evita enviar los mensajes de error relativos al servidor en una respuesta al cliente, ya que de esa forma expones parte de la tecnología usada y eso te puede hacer vulnerable. Si te das cuenta, el mensaje de error en el bloque `catch` lo he cambiado por algo más genérico.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.